# Failed to mount E:\

Tags: system-installation

I started Ubuntu 22.04 lts and it started with failed to mount E:\
from this point I can not setup a user name or password.
This is my first time using Ubuntu or any Linux operating system
Please help

Comment: `E:` is a pretending-to-be "disk", provided by Windows. Linux doesn't pretend, and has no idea what `E:` is.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? On a dual-boot disk? A separate disk? What happens when you try to manually mount this disk?

Comment: is this in WSL?

Comment: E: is a *label* which can be used to refer to a disk drive, a disk partition, a network share (be it drive, disk partition, drive array or more) and more... ie. it's a LABEL used by some old OSes (PC-DOS) to refer to different floppy drives that is still used today in windows (which can from DOS). If you're using a modern windows you'll note drives actually have different names in the OS (which are close to what GNU/Linux uses), but still hides that (behind the LABELS end-users find easier; ie. simple-letters.  What you're after is unclear.

Comment: yes it is WSL and the windows Ubuntu 22.04 app, I now have got passed that problem but it will not install the x11 apps